# Bash Scripting - AWK with Delimiter?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I've got a header in a text file that looks like this:

`First-Name:Last-Name:City:Home-Phone:Cell-Phone`

What I need to do is display the `Last-Name` and the `Cell-Phone` number of each entry.

I'm new to bash scripting, and I'm not really sure what I can use to do this. I was told `awk` could be useful, but after looking around, I still don't quite understand how to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify field separator with `-F`:

```
awk -F":" '{print $2, $5}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/) to be a useful utility for dealing with files like this. It's a lot more intuitive than the low-level unix utilities, though admittedly less powerful.

Take the following file:

```
First-Name:Last-Name:City:Home-Phone:Cell-Phone
Alice:Ashbury:Boston:111-111-1111:444-444-4444
Bob:Brown:Boston:222-222-2222:555-555-5555
Carol:Chaplin:Chicago:333-333-3333:666-666-6666
```

You can extract the second and fifth columns using `csvcut`:

```bash
csvcut test.csv -d ':' -c 2,5
```

Which gives the following output (including the header row):

```
Last-Name,Cell-Phone
Ashbury,444-444-4444
Brown,555-555-5555
Chaplin,666-666-6666
```

Combining the various csvkit commands together lets you quickly explore your data. For example, the following will filter to all lines with `Boston` as the `City`:

```js
csvformat test.csv -d ':' | csvgrep -m Boston -c 3 | csvcut -c 2,5 | csvlook
```

And `csvlook` gives you pretty-printed output:

```
|------------+---------------|
|  Last-Name | Cell-Phone    |
|------------+---------------|
|  Ashbury   | 444-444-4444  |
|  Brown     | 555-555-5555  |
|------------+---------------|
```

Comment: Interesting.  There's also [csvfix](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/), which is also powerful for manipulating CSV files, but also non-standard.